# docker nginx proxy always returns host refused to connect

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm running a nginx reverse proxy container which has two subdomains. I can't reach either of the pages because it always returns `"the site can't be reached"`.

The proxy is on `localhost` and I added the subdomains to `/etc/hosts`.

When I try my configuration on nginx (installed on pc) everything works fine, but in the docker I get the refused connection. Another thing is when I try to check the logs they are empty, so I don't know where the problem lies.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

This is my `default.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.54/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /rtsp-over-websocket {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.54;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name camera2.localhost;
   
     location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.53/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /rtsp-over-websocket {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.53;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug2.log debug;
}
```

I also docker exec into the container and I can see that the `default.conf` is copied over, but again when I try to check the logs they are just empty.

Comment: How are you running the container

Comment: docker run -d image-name.

Comment: wont you need to map the host port to the container port like `docker run -d -p 80:80 image-name` otherwise how do you expect to reach the port inside the container from the host

Comment: that solved it. i thought that exposing the port in the dockerfile did the same thing

Comment: As detailed on the dockerfile page  `The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.`

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose